# how can i update my avtar in xmpp using iphone SDK?

Tags: iphone, xmpp, openfire

how can i update my avtar - login user avtar (photo) in xmpp using iphone SDK (XMPPStream) ?

i have XMPPvCardAvatarModule (but not having method description) so not able to get how to use its methods to update avtar(image) ?? Can any one post sample code & links to understand that, i am stuck with this problem !! Thanks.

Comment: i have XMPPvCardAvatarModule (but not having method description) so not able to get how to use its methods to update avtar(image) ?? Can any one post sample code & links to understand that, i am stuck with this problem !! Thanks.

Comment: Why do you provide additional information as comment instead of updating your question ? You've asked 120 questions already, so you should have enough experience on SO. But maybe [this article](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) would be a good read.

Comment: ok, now i have updated my question.

Answer (score 2):

Most folks use [XEP-153](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0153.html) for avatars.  But *please* be careful implementing this.  If you get your hash logic wrong, and you don't do negative caching, it wreaks havoc on the network as your client constantly re-queries for vcards that will never match the hash they're given.  Please do NOT set your client to send vcard queries to everyone on your roster every time you log in -- please heed the MUST in the XEP for caching avatars, or do NOT implement this feature.

Also, please be aware the community hopes to one day move to [XEP-84](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0084.html), which has the potential to be more efficient in certain cases.